# Connect an MPX10DP Pressure Sensor to an Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, pressure

I'm literally new to using Arduino, i am trying to build a Pitot Tube to measure airspeed using an MPX10DP differential pressure sensor and i am working with an Arduino Mega 2560.

Honestly, i have studied some tutorials of people building a Pitot Tube but the pressure sensors they use are not available in my region, the only pressure that i could afford is the MPX10DP but i am not sure of how to connect it to my arduino and make it get values.

Can someone help me or guide me a bit?

Comment: start by determining what type of output the sensor provides ... when you know that, then ask how to measure it using an Arduino ... as it stands, your question is not about arduino

Answer (score 1):

That part was originally introduced by Motorola many years ago. It is a silicon strain gauge in a bridge configuration. You need an external amplifier as it only has maybe 50 mVdc output depending on your circuit. It is a relative output voltage depending on how you excite it. The one you have is a differential unit, they also made absolute and gauge units as well.  There were many application notes published on the MPX family of pressure transducers. You may have to look in the Motorola archives to find them. The voltage will be either + or - from your reference point depending on what the differential pressure is. They are not temperature compensated so you need to design that into your circuit as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gil, do you know what kind of amplifier do i need? and also how do I know what resistance band I need?

Comment: Simply look for "application note MPX10DP" there are many, AN840 comes to mind but it has been a lot of years probably in the mid 1990s.